# Code coverage is returning 0% while using withRouter

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

Quick summary - I have a React app. The unit test library is react testing library. The component is enclosed in withRouter from react-router-dom

Problem - The code coverage is showing as 0% even though it shows 8 tests passed and some skipped information. If I take off the component from withRouter, the code coverage shows correct coverage result.

Please check the code below where I am trying to match the snapshot.

```
// Profile.test.js
import React from "react";
import Profile from "./Profile";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { render } from "react-testing-library";

it("renders the component", async () => {
  const container = withRouter(<Profile />);
  expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});

// Profile.js
import react from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Profile = () => {
    return (
        <div>The profile component</div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Profile);
```

I should be able to use withRouter for the component and see the coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I think your test should be something like this:

```
it('renders the component', () => {
  const component = mount(<BrowserRouter><Profile /></BrowserRouter>);
  expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`withRouter` is meant to be used in your application to inject router data.

In your tests you have to render the router as part of your components tree:

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

it('renders the component', () => {
  const { container } = render(<MemoryRouter><Profile /></MemoryRouter>);
  expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I suggest you don't use rely only on snapshot testing if you want to make sure that your application is working correctly.